# How to add basic directions on marker right-click like maps.google.com

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

See [this screenshot](http://projectsacramento.com/new2014/wp-content/themes/projectchurchsacramento/images/googlemaps.png) to see what I'm going for. Just like it is on maps.google.com, I'd like to right click on the marker and have it bring up an option for directions. I'm trying to look through the Google Maps API3 Developer's Guide, but I'm having trouble finding a solution. Here's my current code:

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.578809, -121.493758);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: myLatlng,
    streetViewControl: false,
    scaleControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    }
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemaps'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Project Church Downtown'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for appears simple but actually requires quite a bit of work.

I suggest looking at this reverse geocoding guide:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

as well as this directions service guide:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Directions service example:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

You will need to determine the start point, either from a mobile user's current GPS or a desktop users approximate location using HTML5 geolocation. And then process the end point clicked and route the two locations.

For starters you can get the coordinates for a rightclick event.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function(event) {
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
});
```

Comment: I think I should specify that I want the user to simply type in their starting address the "traditional" way. Does that change anything?

Comment: Not quite sure what the desired process is, but it does not matter. I was just offering methods for grabbing api-usable coordinates for both start and end positions.